# It seems as though firewatir is not being found when trying to run my script?

Tags: watir, firewatir

I am very new at Ruby and am having an issue when trying to run my script using watir.

I am getting this error:

"./watir.rb:4:in `require': no such file to load -- firewatir (LoadError)
    from ./watir.rb:4
    from watir.rb:3:in`require'
    from watir.rb:3"

Any help would be great!

Thanks!

Curtis

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How did you install the gem?

Try adding this at the top of your script:

```
require "rubygems"
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I actually needed to do this. I also found out once I added this that I needed to enable Jssh by doing the following /Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox-bin -Jssh Thanks for your help though.